# Elastic search Query String Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get records using the **Query String Query** .
My scenario for searching is as follows :
I have to search like : `"I Love my " AND (HTC OR Iphone OR Samsung)`
And I am expecting result like :

- I Love my HTC
- I Love my Iphone
- I Love my Samsung

I just tried some combinations but its not working

```
{
  "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "default_field": "SearchContent",
               "query": "\"I Love my\" AND (HTC OR Iphone OR Samsung)"
            }
        }
}
```

How can i do this with Query String Or is there any Other Option  , i am stuck.
    Help me out.

Comment: Your query looks correct. mgm's answer (lower case) could be it. So, check your analyzers.

Answer (score 9):

The query depends on your _mapping. If you haven't defined any, then probably the standard analyzer is used.
If so then tokens are:

- I Love my HTC -> "i", "love", "my", "htc"
- I Love my Iphone -> "i", "love", "my", "iphone"
- I Love my Samsung -> "i", "love", "my", "samsung"

notice the tokens are lowercase.

The proper format for your query string is:

```
GET /yourindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "SearchContent",
      "query": "\"i love my\" AND (samsung OR htc OR iphone)"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes. You can build a filtered quesry based on a match_all query with the filters that interest you, combinig and or or filters. Here, you want to return docs that have one of thoses 3 phrases. I assume you do not want "I love my cake, and I have a iphone" to return.

So, something like that (do not know if it is efficient enough, tough).

```
{
"filtered" : {
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "filter" : {
        "or" : {
            "filters" : [{
                    "fquery" : {
                        "query" : {
                            "query_string" : {
                                "query" : "\"I love my iphone\"",
                                "default_field" : "searchContent",
                                "default_operator" : "and"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },{
                    "fquery" : {
                        "query" : {
                            "query_string" : {
                                "query" : "\"I love my htc\"",
                                "default_field" : "searchContent",
                                "default_operator" : "and"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "fquery" : {
                        "query" : {
                            "query_string" : {
                                "query" : "\"I love my samsung\"",
                                "default_field" : "searchContent",
                                "default_operator" : "and"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the Reply .

But i don't have an Fixed values as I  mentioned .

Query may be Anything like : 

    "\"I have my own\" AND (Laptop OR Bike OR Chopper)"

As i gone through various Posts , they Suggest to use "**Query String Query**" which converts it into boolean Logic that we passed, But here i didn't get that Output.



Thanks,

Aniruddha

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
{
  "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "default_field": "SearchContent",
               "query": "I Love my *"

            }
        }
}
```

Wild card doesn't scale well if the data is too large. But, this can be of some help if performance is not a major concern (less amount of data).

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below query string to search for the same.

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "fields" : ["content", "my_field"],
        "query" : "\"I love my \" HTC Iphone Samsung"

    }
}
```

Try this it may workout for you. or check : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: By default, all terms are OR-connected. Therefore, this search would not necessarily contain "I love my".